# How do I use mov si, word[ecx] in my x86 assembly code with MASM?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, masm32

I have a set of instructions in x86 assembly code that looks like the following:

```
[0x401240]
mov edx, str.HelloWorld
mov eax, ecx
push esi
   |
   |
   v
[0x401248]
mov si, word [eax]
cmp si, word [edx]
jne 0x40126e
```

Where `ecx` is the string that I pass into the program once it's running. I'm completely new to assembly, so I'm not entirely sure what's going on here, but I think the line `mov si, word [eax]` is saying "take two bytes from `eax` and set `si` equal to that. In order to test this, I wanted to write my own little script to print out to the console the results of this operation. So using tutorials from the internet, I put this together:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none

include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include \masm32\include\masm32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib

.data
    message db "Hello world!", 0

.code

main:
    mov si, word [message]
    invoke StdOut, si
    invoke ExitProcess, 0
end main
```

Unfortunately, running this via `\masm32\bin\ml /c /Zd /coff test.asm` results in `test.asm(16): error A2009: syntax error in expression`. How can I remedy this and test my hypothesis?

Comment: No, take 2 bytes from memory, using EAX as the address for the load.  The `[]` makes it an addressing mode referring to a memory operand.  For MASM, it's `word ptr` instead of just `word`.  It looks like you found a NASM syntax example, because `mov si, word [message]` is valid NASM syntax.

Comment: *"In order to test this"* - use debugger. In ASM there's high likeliness you will destroy/modify something while trying to produce meaningful debug output, while debuggers are verified and robust solution how to check complete CPU state after each single instruction. If you mention MASM, you probably have VS, which should have debugger included.

Comment: @PeterCordes Because a variable that "holds" a string is simply a pointer that points to the memory address of the first character in the string, does "take 2 bytes from eax" and "take 2 bytes from the memory that eax points to" *basically* mean the same thing? I'm just trying to wrap my head around this more.

Comment: @Ped7g I'm pretty new to all of this, so I'm not really familiar. Even when I code, my method of debugging is a lot of print statements. I tried using Visual Studio 2017 to debug the .exe file, but while it was able to run the program, it dind't actually log any changes to registers, memory, variables, or anything else. Do you have a recommendation for debuggers? Or a better approach?

Comment: @brittenb I guess you have windows OS, so no, I don't have any recommendation, haven't use windows for 10+ years. Back in around year 2000 when I was developing with windows and VS, it had nice debugger allowing to step over single instruction and check values in registers and memory and much more. I find it hard to believe they removed all of that, so it's probably just not intuitive enough for you to figure it out on first try, check maybe some tutorial or help... but I have no idea how exactly that thing works now, decade later... (in linux check "edb-debugger" or any UI for "gdb")

Comment: @Ped7g my host OS is Linux, but I have windows VMs. I'll look into gdb, but for some reason thought it didn't work for exe files... I'll research it more. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @brittenb sure, you can't run exe files under linux, the executables are platform-specific. (you can actually run exe files under linux with "wine", which is sort of windows emulator, but then the gdb will debug not only the code of the exe, but also code of the "wine", as that's the native part running under linux). If you are interested into particular windows exe, then check the Visual Studio debugger better, there should be some way to debug machine code in it, really... Or write linux assembly (NASM can be used for both, so syntax will be same, but OS service calls are different).

Comment: Oh wait, you use MASM, so syntax is different (to NASM).. and there's no MASM for linux. (although the syntax different is minor, while the OS service calls and available API is completely different and you have to basically re-learn/re-write anything OS specific when porting linux assembly to windows or other way)

Comment: @brittenb: "take 2 bytes from eax" would be to copy the low 2 bytes of EAX, *without* dereferencing it.  i.e. `mov si, ax`.  Sounds like it's a terminology problem: you were thinking about it as a load from that address, but the words you used would more accurately describe a register-to-register `mov` (which is also possible, but usually not useful in this case).  Some asm newbies actually do get mixed up between pointers vs. pointed-to data, and what `[]` means in asm syntax.  (Especially if they aren't familiar with pointers in C, I think.)

Comment: Also, asm doesn't really have "variables"; that's a high-level concept you can implement in asm with registers and / or labeled memory locations.  Your `message db "Hello world!", 0` doesn't store a pointer anywhere.  It's like `static char message[] = { ... };` in C.  The label doesn't really exist at runtime, it's just an assemble-time thing to let you reference that address.  So `mov eax, OFFSET message` would put a pointer to the string in a register, with `mov r32, imm32` machine instruction. So the pointer would only be stored in the instruction stream as an immediate, not loaded as data

Comment: @PeterCordes There is so much to learn. To try to put a bow on the "take 2 bytes from eax" concept, are you saying that if `esi` pointed to `0x12345678` and `eax` pointed to, say, `0x01135790`, "copy the low 2 bytes from EAX _without_ dereferencing" would mean `mov si, ax` (like you said), and so `esi` is now `0x01345678`? Or would it become `0x12345690`?

Comment: `mov si, ax` doesn't involve memory *at all*.  I'm going to assume you meant `esi`'s *value* is `0x12345678` (which might or might not be a valid address where something is stored, we don't care unless maybe we have a pointer into a 64k-aligned buffers and we want to replace the low 16 address bits with a new offset).  There's no "pointed to" going on here.  Anyway, the value in `esi` would become `0x12345790`, replacing the least-significant 2 bytes of the full ESI register (aka SI), leaving the upper bytes unmodified.  [x86 partial register usage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21927000).

Comment: Pointers are just integers.  When you're not dereferencing them, there's nothing special about them.  In asm, everything is just bytes; it's up to you to do the right things to the right data.  Also remember that 1 byte = 2 hex digits.  That's why a 32-bit (4-byte) register takes 8 digits.  `SI` is the low half of ESI.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Okay, I need to spend more time tonight fully grokking this. Thanks for your help and insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mov si, word [message]` is NASM syntax. The equivalent in MASM is

```
mov si, word ptr [message]
```

Almost all procedures for 32-bit Windows need DWORDs as argument(s). `SI` is a WORD. Change

```
invoke StdOut, si
```

to

```
invoke StdOut, esi
```

The MASM32 procedure `StdOut` needs a pointer to a null terminated string. With `MOV` you get the value, not the pointer Use `LEA` to get the pointer. Change

```
mov si, word ptr [message]
```

to

```
lea esi, [message]
```

Alternatively you can load the pointer immediately:

```
mov esi, OFFSET message
```

The answer to your underlying problem is: `mov si, word [eax]` loads the WORD that is pointed by `EAX` into the register `SI` which is the lower part of `ESI`. The script to test should look like:

```
INCLUDE \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc

.data
    message db "Hello world!", 0

.code

main:
    xor esi, esi
    mov eax, OFFSET message
    mov si, WORD PTR [eax]

    printf ("0x%x",esi)

    invoke ExitProcess, 0
end main
```

Comment: This is excellent, thank you! I need to wrap my head around it, but using your code works.